# How do I revoke access to updating a custom parameter in postgres? I get syntax error

Tags: postgresql

I want to to this in this order

- Connect to the database as the database owner
- Execute a `set app.foo = bar;` statement
- Change to a less privileged role `set role foo_role`
- Do what ever I want to do with `foo_role`

Is important to me to not let the `foo_role` to set the `app.foo` setting, I tried this

```sql
revoke set on parameter app.foo from foo_role
```

But I get this error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'app.foo'"
LINE 1: revoke set on parameter "app.foo" from foo_role;
```

Looking at the documentation I have this

```
REVOKE [ GRANT OPTION FOR ]
    { { SET | ALTER SYSTEM } [, ...] | ALL [ PRIVILEGES ] }
    ON PARAMETER configuration_parameter [, ...]
    FROM role_specification [, ...]
    [ GRANTED BY role_specification ]
    [ CASCADE | RESTRICT ]
```

I couldn't find any example of `configuration_parameter`

Any idea?

Comment: There is no such setting afaik. Apart from `ROLE`, any client can set any session variable.

Comment: Thanks @FrankHeikens it was a typo, I fixed